# Why were force-sensitives never regulated by the galaxy at large?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

I always wondered why the Jedi and Sith were allowed for millennia to have such a drastic impact on galactic politics despite being less than 1% of the population.

Virtually all of the largest wars in the verse have featured powerful force-wielders at the heart of the conflict, and much evidence points to the average citizen making little distinction between Jedi and Sith. Why didn't the leaders of the non force-sensitive majority prevent force sensitives from organizing themselves and gaining so much power politically and otherwise? After thousands of years I figure heads of state would recognize the dangers and take control over cultivation of force sensitives.

P.s: The only anti-force groups I know of is the Star Cabal from SWTOR MMO, and they were made into more of a criminal organization, but any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: *Allowed*? So you're advocating what? Force genocide?

Comment: I’ve removed the [jedi] and [sith] tags because this question is about anti-Jedi/-sith groups.

Comment: @Paulie_D I mean why force user groups are able to almost always assume control of organizations to further their war.

Comment: The Jedi weren't *in control* and the Sith was hiding in plain sight as a Senator. Plus *regulating* minorities **never** works well....never!

Comment: I mean the EU and current new continuity as a whole. Since the EU's Great Hyperspace War, the most destructive conflicts have had Jedi and Sith at the head, yet they were always allowed the role of exalted protectors of the republic despite times (Kotor era) indicating that the average person found little distinction between the two groups.

Comment: Stayin in the movies, the Jedi were still made into military officers and political advisors. Vader used his powers openly even if Palpatine kept his hidden, same as Kylo Ren

Comment: The question is how much success would such an organization have.....as we have seen even single jedi and sith are VERY powerful and can easily defeat a whole army (of droids / clones / stormtroopers) if not taken by a surprise betrayal.

Comment: Why in the galaxy would someone do that? Force users are any army's biggest asset. You might as well ask why no Earth government seeks to kill anyone who can fly a fighter jet.

Comment: The Jedi Order identifies infants who possess the greatest Force-sensitivity, conscripting and raising them with a lifelong prohibition on reproduction.  Same effect, given enough time.

Answer (score 8):

### The Republic relies on the Jedi as peacekeepers

> For over a thousand generations, the Jedi Knights were the guardians of peace and justice in the Old Republic.

Obi-Wan says that the Jedi were the peacekeepers of the Old Republic, and the prequel trilogy reveals that the Republic does not have a standing military (aside from the surprise creation of the Clone army). So suppressing the people who are keeping order among the entire Republic is a sure way to create a disaster.

And fortunately, the Jedi are usually good guys. They tend to end battles, rather than start them.

### The Sith are hidden

Prior to *The Phantom Menace*, the Sith have not been seen in generations and there were known to be at most two of them. Given that, there wasn’t teally any way to track them down and suppress them.

### How would you do it anyway?

The Jedi were largely eliminated by Order 66, which involved putting them in charge of a Clone army, sending them to their own planets, and then having them turn on them. In other words, killing an entire order of Force users is hard, and the Republic didn’t have the means to do it before the Clone Wars.

### In Legends, Darth Traya became the closest to destroying all Force users

*Knights of the Old Republic II: The Sith Lords* featured the [First Jedi Purge](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/First_Jedi_Purge). By the end of it, there were only a dozen or so Force users left, and the Force itself was almost permanently destroyed.

> Only a handful of us remained after the Jedi Civil War, barely a hundred in number. Then even that hundred began to disappear, in places where the Force seemed blind. The only pattern we determined [was] that when Jedi gathered, they were seen no more. At the last Jedi conclave on Katarr, the entire planet was wiped out. An entire race, destroyed… because the Jedi chose to gather there. It was only then that we realized that we were facing something far more powerful than we knew how to fight.
>
> –Jedi Master Zez-Kai Ell

First, the Sith Triumvirate led by Darth Traya trained Sith assassins to seek out Jedi, drawn to when they congregated together. By the time of the game, there were only a handful of them left.

Darth Traya was overthrown by the two others in the Triuumverate. She took the name Kreia and became disillusioned, deciding that everything bad that happened to the galaxy was the result of the Force, and that the best solution was to destroy it outright.

To make a very long story short, Kreia discovered that “The Exile” (the protagonist of the game) was the only survivor of an experimental weapon that had an unintended side effect of creating “sounds in the Force” and that they themselves had become such a wound. Kreia’s plan was to manipulate The Exile into creating a wound in the Force so big that it would kill every Force user in the entire Galaxy, or even destroy the Force outright.

> It is said that the Force has a will, it has a destiny for us all. I wield it, but it uses us all, and that is abhorrent to me. Because I hate the Force. I hate that it seems to have a will, that it would control us to achieve some measure of balance, when countless lives are lost. But in you… I see the potential to see the Force die, to turn away from its will. And that is what pleases me. You are beautiful to me, exile. A dead spot in the Force, an emptiness in which its will might be denied.
>
> –Darth Traya to “The Exile”

She was of course stopped, and the Exile (in the canonical Light Side ending) set out to revive the Jedi Order.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that Force users generally win battles, rather than starting them. Who tries to get rid of their best weapons? Trying to kill Force users would be the action of an ideologue, *not* a pragmatist.